# How to show double quotes " " in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, escaping

I have an insert query where the data to be inserted comes from textareas. After inserting it, I want show the this content in other textarea. I have a problem with double quotes...I don't know how to manage it because the output textarea doesn't show text containing " " !

I tried htmlentitles and other functions, but nothing happened. Can you please help me? Thank you so much.

This is input code:

```
//database connection
//taking datas from the text areas input in the form
$title = trim(stripslashes($_POST['title']));
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
```

This is output code:

```
//select query
$title=mysql_result($results, $i,"T_TITLE");
//and with javascript I want show it in a textarea that have name="EDITtitle"
document.EDITform.EDITtitle.value="<?php echo $title; ?>";
```

If in input I have -  PROBLEM WITH "CODE N1" IN THE SITE, how can I show text with " " , without problems?

Comment: `document.EDITform.EDITtitle.value='<?php echo $title; ?>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `htmlspecialchars` function.

```
document.EDITform.EDITtitle.value="<?php echo htmlspecialcahrs($title); ?>";
```

Comment: and what about `document.EDITform.EDITtitle.value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '\"', $title); ?>";`

Comment: I used replace, is the only way it works :D thank you!
can I ask you another thing? How can I manage text with new lines? Is correctly saved in my database, my if I pass it to a textarea, I don't see it!

Answer (score 1):

```
string addslashes ( string $str )
```

this function used to add slash before quotes

Use "**addslashes**" function to before inserting db

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

```
stripslashes($str);
```

this function used to remove slashes

Use "**stripslashes**" function to view the content

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code-only answer.

Comment: @JEricaM "htmlspecialchars_decode" use this function